# Can I delay the rotation of the logfile when using the Twisted logger?

Tags: python, logging, twisted

When using the `logging` module to create rotating log files, I can tell the logger to delay the rotation until there is actual data to be logged by using the `delay=True` argument of the `TimedRotatingFileHandler` class like this:

```py
import time
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('logfile.log', when='midnight', delay=True)
    out_fmt = '[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03dZ] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s'
    dt_fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime
    formatter = logging.Formatter(out_fmt, dt_fmt)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    root.addHandler(handler)
```

This is useful when there is rarely any new information output to the log - for instance, if there is a whole day without anything new being logged; then you don't want to create an empty log file for that day.

Is it possible to achieve the same effect when using the Twisted logger (`twisted.python.logfile.DailyLogFile`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired behavior, simply by overriding `shouldRotate` function in `DailyLogFile` class.

Something like below should do the trick:

```py
class CustomDailyLogFile(LogFile, DailyLogFile):
    def shouldRotate(self):
        return self.toDate() > self.lastDate and self.rotateLength and self.size >= self.rotateLength
```

Comment: I understand the idea and I like it but it seems that I cannot access `rotateLength` and `size` like this. These variables are local for the `LogFile` class - not for the `DailyLogFile` class.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that. You can add the other class too. I will edit the answer.